A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: IMAGE_PROCESS_FAILED
#id= переменная
#Messages = список
#pols = список 
for i in messages:  
    bot.send_photo(id, i)
    bot.send_message(id, f"отправил с ID: {pols[0]}")

как решить эту проблему? выдаёт ошибку:

A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: IMAGE_PROCESS_FAILED


Ошибка, которую Вы получаете, сообщает о том, что эндпоинт Telegram API не смог обработать переданную картинку. Приложите полный код скрипта, т.к. в данном отрывке непонятно как и из чего формируется список картинок для отправки.
